# if the name exists in the Excel, check if a folder for that name exists, if true copy the Folder

Tags: python, pandas, excel, algorithm, directory

I've been working on this for days but no luck. I have some folder in another folder and I need to check if the Name of these folders appear on a Excel sheet. If so I want to copy the files to another folder. It seems easy job to be, but I'm kind of new to python so I'm lost.

An Example of the list of names in excel file:

```
[mike nicolai Tesla, Thomas Edison, Edie Morphy, Josef mike Tesla Johanssen]
```

an example of the directories, this is a over all schema R:\this folder\Folder\Subfolder\lastName, first Name

```
R:\this folder\docs\GERMANY\Tesla Johanssen, Josef mike
R:\this folder\docs\GERMANY\Morphy, Edie   
R:\this folder\docs\France\nicolai Tesla, Josef mike
```

I have made these Functions, in order to Copy or extract the names accordingly. Due to the middle names, I had to check if the Function returns more than just First and Last Name. I have 2 functions for that purpose *sort_Names(_name)* & *extract_Names_From_Folders(folder_path)*

```
import os
from glob import glob
import shutil

def extract_Names_From_Folders(folder_path):
    folder_Name=folder_path.split(sep="\\")
    folder_Name=folder_Name[-1::]
    if len(''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(' '))>2:
        _lName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[0]
        _mName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[1]
        _fName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[2]
        return _fName,_mName,_lName
    elif len(''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(' '))>1:
        _lName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[0]
        _fName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[1]            
        return _fName,_lName
    elif len(''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(' '))>0:
        _fName=''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(" ")[0]  
        return _fName
    
def sort_Names(_name):
    if len(''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" "))==4:  
        excel_fName2=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[3]
        excel_fName1=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[2]
        excel_mName= ''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[0]
        excel_lName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[1]
        return excel_fName1,excel_fName2,excel_mName,excel_lName
    elif len(''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" "))==3:  
        excel_fName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[2]
        excel_mName= ''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[0]
        excel_lName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[1]
        return excel_fName,excel_mName,excel_lName
    elif len(''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" "))==2:
        excel_fName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[1]        
        excel_lName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[0]
        return excel_fName,excel_lName
    elif len(''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" "))==1:
        excel_fName=''.join(map(str, _name)).split(" ")[0]        
        return excel_fName
    else: return [0]


def copy_the_file(folder_name,_name,df):    
    index = _name.index(folder_name)        
    df.at[_name, "User Request Form Created?\n[Yes/No]"] = "Yes"
    # Copy the subfolder to the Proof folder
    proof_folder_path = r"r:\blabla\Proof"
    shutil.copytree(folder_name, os.path.join(proof_folder_path, _name), dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Here's the main part. This code doesn't currently work I have no idea *why*. It got complex so fast. I'm pretty sure it can be done in easier and more pythonic way. But have no clue how.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

# Set up file paths
excel_file_path = r"k:\blabla\path.xlsx"
folder_path = r"r:\blabla\path\*\*"
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, header=1)

# Get the list of names from the "Name" column
names = df["Name"].tolist()
for folder_name in glob(folder_path, recursive = True):
    #Check if function returns 3 or 2 variables. A function returns a Tuple
    mName=''
    tuple_=extract_Names_From_Folders(folder_name)
    if len(tuple_) == 3:
        fName = tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None
        mName= tuple_[1] if len(tuple_) > 1 else None
        lName= tuple_[2] if len(tuple_) > 2 else None
    elif len(tuple_) == 2:
        fName = tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None        
        lName= tuple_[1] if len(tuple_) > 1 else None
    elif len(tuple_) == 1:
        fName = tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None

    #convert list to string then split by comma
    # print(''.join(map(str, folder_Name)).split(',')[0])
    
    for _name in names: 
        if len(_name)>2:
            tuple_=sort_Names(_name)
            if len(tuple_) == 4:
                excel_fName2=tuple_[1] if tuple_ else None
                excel_fName1=tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None
                excel_mName= tuple_[2] if tuple_ else None
                excel_lName=tuple_[3] if tuple_ else None
                print(excel_fName1+' '+excel_fName2,excel_mName+' '+excel_lName)      
  # Check if the subfolder matches a name in the Excel file      
                if excel_fName1+' '+excel_fName2 == fName and excel_mName+" "+excel_lName == lName:       
                    copy_the_file(folder_name,_name,df)
            if len(tuple_) == 3:            
                excel_fName=tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None
                excel_mName= tuple_[1] if tuple_ else None
                excel_lName=tuple_[2] if tuple_ else None
                print(excel_fName+' '+excel_mName,excel_lName)
                if excel_fName == fName and excel_mName+" "+excel_lName == lName:       
                    copy_the_file(folder_name,_name,df)
            elif len(tuple_) == 2:
                excel_fName = tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None        
                excel_lName = tuple_[1] if len(tuple_) > 1 else None
                print(excel_fName +' '+excel_lName)            
                if excel_fName==fName and excel_lName == lName:
                    copy_the_file(folder_name,_name,df)
            elif len(tuple_) == 1:
                fName = tuple_[0] if tuple_ else None
```

Comment: Please place part of excel file with names and part of directory with folder names.

Comment: @СергейКох i added the Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `difflib` module to find similar names. By matching in the `.get_close_matches` method, you can try to find the closest value. For the data you gave, `cutoff=.5` came up. If it doesn't work out, you can sort the words in the dataframe lines, convert them to the same case, so that the comparisons are more accurate. If this fails, you can use third-party libraries to compare strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import shutil
import difflib

excel_file_path = r'test.xlsx'
folder_path = r'F:\this folder\docs'
proof_folder_path = r'F:\this folder\Proof'

df_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, names=['name'], dtype='string')

pathes = glob.glob(rf'{folder_path}\*\*')

# We create lists, one with a partial path to the folders, the second with their names.
part_path = [part for path in pathes for part in path.split(sep=r"\docs")[-1::]]
folder_name = [name for path in pathes for name in path.split(sep="\\")[-1::]]

# We collect everything in another dataframe.
dict_folder = {'name': folder_name, 'path': pathes, 'part_path': part_path}
df_folder = pd.DataFrame(dict_folder, dtype='string')

# We start a cycle of checking folder names and overwriting the necessary ones.
for name in df_excel['name']:
    # You may have to match `cutoff=`, so for data that is 0.4 selected and unnecessary, 0.6 did not select any.
    find_it = difflib.get_close_matches(name, df_folder['name'], n=1, cutoff=.5)
    
    # If the name matches, overwrite the subfolder in a new folder.
    if find_it:
        df_path = df_folder.loc[df_folder['name'] == find_it[0]]
        shutil.copytree(df_path['path'].values[0],
                        f"{proof_folder_path}{df_path['part_path'].values[0]}",
                        dirs_exist_ok=True)
```